# Can't access the Documents directory when iPhone is getting locked?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, lockscreen, documentsdirectory

**Scenario 1**. I used this code for downloading files from Dropbox using Dropbox SDK.

```
-(void)downloadFile:(DBMetadata*)file
{
    if (!file.isDirectory)
    {
        NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *localPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file.filename];

        [[self restClientForDownload] loadFile:file.path intoPath:localPath];

    }

}
```

**Scenario 2.** Whenever I want to play the songs from Documents directory. it won't play when iPhone is **getting Password Locked.** Current song also stopped with in fraction of seconds.

Comment: You want to proceed playing audio when your app goes to background?

Comment: ya.. i want to proceed playing audio or download the files from cloud. but i need to access the documents directory when iPhone locked? @Volker

Comment: Is background modes turned on?

Comment: ya. i turned on it XCODE -> CAPABILITIES-> under Background modes. The options i checked 1. Audio&airplay,2.BackgroundFetch

Comment: Sounds like the file was saved with the `NSFileProtection` attribute set to `NSFileProtectionComplete`.

Comment: Ya. I tired with Data Protection in Xcode. I used the Attributes like NSFileProtectionComplete. Whenever I download the files from cloud, I set this Attribute to that particular file. But it also won't Work. @Austin

Comment: @Ranjith http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425968/play-video-in-background-using-avplayer try this

Comment: This issue was Fixed with help of NSFileProtection API. Thanks @Austin

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. However, you can "prevent" your phone from locking when your app is running. [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES should do it.

Comment: I tired this not working when phone is getting locked. If i downloading any content using nsurl session & playing any songs from documents directory. @Bullet Raja

Comment: if u r using the these kind of task then phone will not locked till ur app is open and u can access ur document directory easily once u have done just set [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO